# Client/server multithreading and ConcurrentHashMap - why isn't clients.get(id) being locked?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, concurrenthashmap

I have the following block of code in my server:

```
clients.putIfAbsent(id, new Integer(0));
synchronized (clients.get(id)) {
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        x = new Integer(((Integer) o).intValue());
        value = clients.get(id); // existing value in HashMap
        value = new Integer(value.intValue() + x);
        clients.put(id, value);
    } else if (o instanceof String) {
        clients.put(id, new Integer(0));
    }
    Thread.sleep(SockServer5.sleepTime);
out.writeObject(clients.get(id));
    out.flush();
}
```

`clients` is a ConcurrentHashMap, while `o` is the object input being read from the client.  For each new client connection, the server spawns a new thread.

I would like to know, is there any particular reason why my `clients.get(id)` isn't being locked?

Comment: Each calling thread is probably synchronizing on a different object since "id" would have a different value and therefore return a different object. You should synchronized on the same object only.

Comment: My test bombards my server using a single id, then two, then three, then 10, all doing 100 connections each total.  Each time the number of id's double, it should take about half as much time as the previous.  I have tested this, and this clearly isn't happening.

Comment: You have a clients.get(id) which will return either 0 or another int value and you are locking on this integer value. Not sure what you intend to gain from this, but its not going to lock anything that affects the code inside the synchronized block

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, `cleints.get(id)` returns an instance of an Object and you are synchronizing on it. Fine. That does not prevent access to the concurrent hashmap by another thread. I suspect you want to prevent access to the Hashmap, in which cas you should use an Object() as a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, `clients.get(id)` returns an instance of an Object and you are synchronizing on it.

Fine.

That does not prevent access to the concurrent hashmap by another thread. I suspect you want to prevent access to the Hashmap, in which case you should use an Object() as a mutex

Answer (score 0):

In both branches of your *if* statement, you are putting a new object into the map. Therefore all other threads will find a different object as result of client.get(id). Even if you have two equal integers in the map, they are not same objects. 
Example: if 'o' is always a string, each execution of the code will replace the value in the map, and each following thread will get a new object in client.get() (well some may be lucky enough to get a previous object, but most will get a new one, since the synchronized block is rather small and fast comparing to stream handling and your sleep (because the object gets replaced, before the sleep finishes)).

If you want to synchronize on a non-existing object, on the idea (or id) of the object, check out this github repo: https://github.com/anotheria/idbasedlock

Answer (score 0):

Two things: first

> One shall not use new Integer but [Integer.valueOf(i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29)

The other thing is that there isn't even a need to use synchronized. It completely defies the reason to use a concurrent map, because it throttles down threads to single-threaded thanks to blocking. Here is a solution that does not use synchronized but is still thread-safe:

```
clients.putIfAbsent(id, Integer.valueOf(0));

Integer value;
do {
  value = clients.get(id);
} while (clients.replace(id, value, value + o) == false); // repeat until value did not change in between

Thread.sleep(SockServer5.sleepTime);
out.writeObject(value);
out.flush();
```

Where `clients` is defined as (replace String with whatever you use):

```
final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> clients;
```

This uses the same concept as [compareAndSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet%28int,%20int%29) does in other Atomics: it repeats until no thread interfered in between. The big benefit is that no thread needs to be blocked, so on a multi-core machine all cores can be used at 100% **all the time**.

Please note as well the usage of automatic boxing of Integers in `value + o`. Java will use the most efficient form here on its own.